# Why Chrome DevTool device toolbar doesn't works properly with different stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I'm not sure if it's a problem related with the devtool device toolbar, but given the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen and (max-width: 700px)' href='css/style_smartphone.css' />
      <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen and (min-width: 701px)' href='css/style_tablet.css' />
      <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
    </html>
```

and these 2 stylesheet:

style_tablet.css

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background: black;
}
```

style_smartphone.css

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background: blue;
}
```

i can see the background change when i reduce the window size, but it doesn't change when i switch width from the devtool device toolbar.

Did i make any mistake with my media query?

Comment: I tested this out on my home PC and i was able to replicate your problem. Today I have tested it on my work MAC using Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) and it works as expected... I will try again on PC and get back to you.

Comment: did you find time to test it?

Comment: Ok so after some more testing i discovered that it works when using the live preview feature in dreamweaver, which is what i was using on my MAC. but just opening it normally in chrome worked as you experienced it.

Comment: thanks, i opened a issue on the github repository. I 'll update here as soon as the problem will be discussed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure how your code doesn't react like it should but it's good practice to put it in a style sheet. Below is what I've tested quickly.

***HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>test</title>
</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

***Style***

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width:300px) {
    body {
        background: blue;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    } }

@media screen and (min-width: 1001px) {
    body {
        background: black;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    } }
```

Comment: I don't know what the limitations are with the media queries. I found some inconsistent behaviors when referring to two style sheets or when trying to  query three sizes.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but I need to figure out the solution to the problem described :)